# What if we make the Optional.of method private, and only allow Optional.ofNullable in Java; would there be any problem except backwards-compatibility?

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, null, option-type

This question has to be updated because it is marked as duplicated, but all the linked questions are not completely matching what is tried to be asked:

**Is there a reason, that `Optional.of(aNullableVar)` is required, as `Optional.ofNullable(aNullableVar)` checks for null pointer inner the method?**

As [what Savior answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54662285/what-if-we-make-the-optional-of-method-private-and-only-allow-optional-ofnullab/54662322#54662322), a purpose may be like a guard clause:

```
Object object = getObject();
Optional.of(object);
System.out.println(object.toString());
```

It's equivalent to:

```
Object object = getObject();
Objects.requireNonNull(object);
System.out.println(object.toString());
```

and

```
Object object = getObject();
if (object == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
System.out.println(object.toString());
```

---

Optional.of in Java 8:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value) {
    return new Optional<>(value);
}
```

Optional.ofNullable in Java 8:

```
public static <T> Optional<T> ofNullable(T value) {
    return value == null ? empty() : of(value);
}
```

Comment: Define _problem_.

Comment: *except*? that is a big except in the `java` world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Optional.of` serves a double purpose of constructing an `Optional` with the given non-`null` value, but also *failing fast* if the value is actually `null`.

It's analogous to doing

```
Objects.requireNonNull(value);
// and then using value
```

So nothing would really break, you'd just find out much later that you used a `null` value to create that `Optional` when you shouldn't have.